# Conga's Nth row syntax not working

Tags: query, merge-field, conga

So I have a data set from a conga query called guarantors and need to reference field values from the 1st and 2nd rows. I have tried using the syntax from conga but it will not work:

```
{{Guarantor.CONTACT_NAME.0}}
{{Guarantor.CONTACT_NAME.1}}
```

The Guarantor data set does bring in values since if I add this :

```
{{TableStart:Guarantor}}{{CONTACT_NAME}}{{TableEnd:Guarantor}}
```

Then both values are shown, though i get both and not an individual value.

Using: `{{TableStart:Guarantor}}{{CONTACT_NAME.0}}{{TableEnd:Guarantor}}`

Doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

What template type are you working with?  The Nth Row Syntax is only supported in PowerPoint and PDF Form templates.  If you only need to reference the first two rows of a dataset, I would encourage you to limit your data.  By using either a "LIMIT 2" in the SOQL Query statement for the "Guarantor" dataset.

*Example:* SELECT Name, Id, Title, Email, Phone, LastName
FROM Contact
WHERE Id = '{pv0}' AND ...
**ORDER BY LastName ASC
LIMIT 2**

SOQL Limit Documentation: [Force.com SOQL Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_limit.htm?search_text=LIMIT)

Never hesitate to give our team a call or email us at support@congamerge.com